# Right join in jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa

**NewRequest.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Size(max = 2147483647)
@Column(length = 2147483647)
private String data;

@JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Buyer buyer_id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "newrequest_id", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Mapping> mappingCollection;
```

**Mapping.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "seller_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Seller seller_id;

@JoinColumn(name = "newrequest_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private NewRequest newrequest_id;
```

Lets say, I have records something like this.

**new_request :**

```
id(PK) |  data  | buyer_id(FK)
------------------------------
1      |  data1 |   1
2      |  data2 |   1
3      |  data3 |   2
```

**mapping :**

```
id(PK) | newrequest_id(FK) | seller_id(FK)
------------------------------------------
1      |        1          |    1
```

Note : consider buyer and seller two different table exist.

I want all new_request which is mapped with seller or not. So, expected Output :

```
id   | data  | buyer_id | seller_id
------------------------------------
1    | data1 |  1       |    1
2    | data2 |  1       |
3    | data3 |  2       |
```

I tried below query in JPA :

```
select n.id,n.data,n.buyer_id,m.seller_id from Mapping m left join m.newrequest_id n
```

which gives only one data (output row no 1).

I got my result with right join using native query. But I want to achieve it using JPA query.

Comment: You didn't give your entity model, which would help to understand your query. Usually I would recommend a `mappedBy` field in your `NewRequest` class. Another remark: Don't call your XToX fields `..._id` - you are referencing entities in JPA, not IDs. So better use `newrequest` instead of `newrequest_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to switch the entity classes in your query (in most cases a *right outer join* is just the *inverse* of an *left outer join*):

```
select n.id, n.data, n.buyer_id, m.seller_id 
  from NewRequest n left join n.mappingCollection m
```

As I already suggested in my comment above: You should remove the `_id` suffix from your attributes, as this is better to read and understand.